# I've calculated and plotted Z Scores using the code below, but how do I transform z scores into t scores?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-science

I'm just getting started with python. I've worked out how to create and plot z scores for my data. The normal convention for this data is that the z scores are adjusted to non-negative t scores. I can't figure out a way to do this that isn't a manual convert (i.e. T = (Z x 10) + 50)

What would be the recommended way to transform and plot Z into T scores?

```
import csv
with open("A018722.csv",'rb') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)      
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
EDAdata = pd.read_csv("A018722.csv")
EDAdata.describe()
EDAdata.mode()
EDAdata = np.genfromtxt('A018722.csv',delimiter=',')
EDAlist = EDAdata.tolist()
from scipy.stats import zscore
df = zscore(EDAlist)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.plot(df)
```

Comment: how many samples do you have? I mean, for a reasonably high `n` the difference is negligeble

Comment: also, looking at the code of scipy zscore, it uses sample std. It is actually t-score

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marat. It's biosignal data read at 4hz so I've got over 10000 individual records in each case (total 15). I want to be able to plot the standardised data as non-negative values.